# What is the meaning of $(·)$ , $(·;\theta)$

Tags: functions

I am reading a paper and have some questions.

What is the meaning of these notation on [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ti6p5.png) picture?

p.s I can't understand do this {($\frac{i-1}{H-1}, \frac{j-1}{W-1}, \frac{k-1}{T-1}$)}. Please explain to me, thank you for reading my question.

Comment: Are you comfortable with the notation $\mathbf{v} : \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: No, it hasn't been long since I started studying, but I haven't seen that kind of notation. However, it seems to be making a change in dimension. ex: torch.transformer

Comment: You may want to look up (or review) function notation then.  Your question is about function naming conventions, not machine learning.  For instance, $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{v}(\cdot)$ are equivalent, and some authors might write $\mathbf{v}(\cdot;\theta)$ as $\mathbf{v}_\theta$ (when it wouldn't be mistaken for e.g. a partial derivative).

Comment: Thank you for answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symbol $\cdot$ is a placeholder. $\boldsymbol v(\cdot)$ means "$\boldsymbol v$ is being treated as being a function of something, but we're not specifying what it's function of". In this case, we have $\boldsymbol v(\cdot): \mathbb R^m \rightarrow \mathbb R ^n$, so $\boldsymbol v$ is a function of $m$ variables. Since $m$ is allowed to vary, the author wants to allow for different numbers of arguments, rather than giving a fixed number.  $\boldsymbol v(\cdot; \theta)$ means $\boldsymbol v$ is a function of an unspecified set of arguments, and also $\theta$.

Comment: thank you for reply so the above formula is the definition of dimension change and any parameter.